# How to retrieve XMPP user information

Tags: objective-c, xmpp, openfire, xmppframework

I need to retrieve user information saved on openfire server.

```
XMPPvCardCoreDataStorage* xmppvCardStorage = [XMPPvCardCoreDataStorage sharedInstance];
XMPPvCardTempModule* m = [[XMPPvCardTempModule alloc] initWithvCardStorage:xmppvCardStorage];
[m fetchvCardTempForJID:[sender myJID]];
```

How/where I can read result of request? Is the right way to "query" openfire server?

I also tryed:

```
XMPPIQ *iq = [[XMPPIQ alloc] initWithType:@"get"];
[iq addAttributeWithName:@"id" stringValue:@"v1"];
[iq addAttributeWithName:@"from" stringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", sender]];
[iq addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"get"];
DDXMLElement *query = [DDXMLElement elementWithName:@"vCard" xmlns:@"vcard-temp"];
[iq addChild:query];
[_xmppStream sendElement:iq];
```

Where sender is XMPPJID of the searched user.

XMPPIQ is successfully sended and debugger enter in method:

```
- (XMPPIQ *)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender willReceiveIQ:(XMPPIQ *)iq;
```

If I print iq I've:

```
<iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="result" id="v1" to=<MYJID> >
    <vCard xmlns="vcard-temp"/>
</iq>
```

Comment: what is your subscription  to ,from or both  and is autoSubscription On in your openFire.